# Can't pay with PayPal balance, only shows credit card to pay with

Tags: credit-card, paypal

I have about $460 USD in my PayPal balance, and my account is verified. I tried to order a flight for about $400, but the only option PayPal provided is to pay from credit card. I called the flight company, and they said that everything is OK on their end.

That's not the first time it happens for me, but that's the first time it's meaningful (a large amount). Why does it happen? How can it be solved?

Screenshot:

[image]

When I click "Change Funding":

[image]

Comment: Give us the screenshot when you press the "Change" link.

Comment: @base64 added a screenshot (sorry for the bad quality).

Comment: A quick Google indicates that if you live in certain countries, you may not use PayPal balance to make international purchases.

Comment: I couldn't find any relevant information about it. Could you please provide a relevant link?

Comment: https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/Buying-with-PayPal/Not-using-my-payPal-balance-to-pay-for-something/td-p/412199

Comment: This is a question for PayPal support. You should ask them directly.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its specific question that PayPal support needs to answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the answer I got from PayPal support (emphasis mine). Perhaps it will be useful to somebody.

> Thank you for contacting PayPal regarding paying with your PayPal balance.
>
> I have reviewed your account and it shows that you have completed you
>   payment using a credit card.
>
> Usually the balance will be taken when you buy an item with the same
>   currency. How ever in some cases the system will automatically choose
>   to take the funds from your credit card in order to give you an
>   addition guarantee if there is a problem with this item or service.
>
> Next time if you see that the fund are not being taken from your
>   balance **try to remove the credit card and only then try to complete the payments. After that you can re-add your credit card.**